# Can this nested-select SQL query be simplified?

Tags: sql, nested

I feel like there should be a simpler way to write this, since both SELECT statements are pulling from the same table:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
WHERE column2 = 'VIRTUAL'
AND column3 IN
  (SELECT column3
   FROM table1
   WHERE column1 = 'ELEC-035A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same query but i replaced the subquery by an `INNER JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT T1.column1
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table1 T2 ON T2.column3 = T1.column3
                       AND T2.column1 = 'ELEC-035A'
WHERE T1.column2 = 'VIRTUAL'
GROUP BY T1.column1
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: add GROUP BY T1.column1 at the end of the query to avoid duplicates, which the original query doesn't have. Or just SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: @PawelP I hesitated to add a `GROUP BY` clause when writing the query and i decided to keep the same logic as the original one. But you're right, it's better to provide a solution that will avoid duplicates.

Comment: Well OK, it's your answer in the end. The logic is not exactly the same because you will get more rows returned than oOP's query (when multiple same values are found in the IN clause, it won't increase the number of results, but for the JOIN it will, since every time you find a match you'll join. Nevertheless, GROUP BY (or select distinct) will give less (or equal) rows than OP's query. I guess with the info we provided, OP will be able to fine-tune the query to his liking. To OP: the only way those queries will differ is in the number of duplicates.